# Did the Tri-Wizard Tournament organizers know Hagrid put in a blast ended skrewt in the maze?

Tags: harry-potter, plot-device, triwizard-tournament

There is this line in GoF before the third event of the TWT

> "We seemply ’ave to get through the maze?” said Fleur.
>
> “There will be obstacles,” said Bagman happily, bouncing on the balls
> of his feet. “**Hagrid is providing a number of creatures** . . . then
> there will be spells that must be broken . . . all that sort of thing,
> you know.

We also find out later that one of these is a Blast-ended skrewt

> The sleeve of his robe was smoking. "Hagrid's Blast-Ended Skrewts!" he
> hissed. "They're enormous - I only just got away!" He shook his head
> and dived out of sight, along another path.

But earlier in the book, Rita Skeeter has written an article, hinting the skrewts might be a new breed bred by Hagrid, and very likely illegal.

> Hagrid has no intention of ceasing his campaign of intimidation,
> however. In conversation with a Daily Prophet reporter last month, he
> admitted breeding creatures he has dubbed "Blast-Ended Skrewts,"
> highly dangerous crosses between manti-cores and fire-crabs. The
> creation of new breeds of magical creature is, of course, an activity
> usually closely observed by the Department for the Regulation and
> Control of Magical Creatures. Hagrid, however, considers himself to be
> above such petty restrictions.

Regardless, the blast ended skrewts seem to be particularly more dangerous than other general obstacles. The Sphinx is arguably more dangerous, but it seemed almost sentient and probably the Ministry had even made a deal with it so that it wouldn't really hurt a student. The skrewt seemed more like a wild animal, like a wolf or a bear, so I am assuming it was more dangerous.

Did the Ministry, or the TWT organizers have any idea that that was the creature Hagrid had provided? How did they let Hagrid put in a highly dangerous and possibly illegal creature like that in the maze? Did the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures get involved at some point and deemed the creatures were not illegal?

Comment: You shouldn't take Rita Skeeter's insinuations as evidence of _anything_.

Comment: @Spencer are you implying she lied here and the skrewts are legal?

Comment: She didn’t precisely say they **were** illegal, now did she?

Comment: @Spencer did imply it, seems something thats likely too

Comment: That's what sleazy reporters do.  So, without any corroboration you can take it as just a smear.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233021/how-did-anyone-expect-champions-in-trouble-to-send-up-red-sparks